# How to get firebase userID from inside a firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

My user is directed from my app to a website which eventually returns a response to a redirect uri. I have a cloud function in firebase which listen for that link and get the response. Now I would like to save that information  along with the details of the firebase user who triggered the process? For example I would like to save the response in Firestore in a document names as the userID. How can I achieve it??

I have added a picture of my process flow
[image]

Here is my function

```
exports.connectStripeStandardAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  let authCode = req.query.code;
  //here I would like to get the uid of the user who triggered the website
  return res.send(authCode);

  });
});
```

Here is the code for step nr 1 (my app is written in flutter)

> link is in this format
>   link = https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=read_write

```
_launchURLWebsite(String link) async {
    if (await canLaunch(link)) {
      await launch(link);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $link';
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: From where exactly are you calling the Cloud Function? From your process flow, it seems it is from the website. Is this correct? If it is from the app, is the user identified through Firebase Authentication? Which kind of Cloud Function do you use? A "simple" HTTPS one or a Callable one?

Comment: The function is triggered by the website. I have added the function for reference above

Comment: What is exactly « the website » ? I guess you have full control on it. Can’t it be merged with the app? It calls the HTTPS Cloud Function through Java Script? Maybe the website is the Stripe API endpoint (from your CF name) and it is a Stripe webhook that calls your CF. We need more details to fully understand your case.

Comment: Yes the website is stripe and I have no control over it

Comment: Ok! Can you also share the code of the button clicked by your user (i.e. how do you call the Stripe API).  What type of app it is? Android?iOS? Web?

Comment: added & it is a flutter app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201760/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-mactrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the different comments to your question, it appears that you are using the Stripe [Connect OAuth Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference) .

The documentation (link above) explains that you can add a `state` parameter to your request, which is "an arbitrary string value we will pass back to you".

So, by adding a `state` parameter to your URL, as follows

```
https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=read_write&state=theuidofyouruser
```

you will receive the value of `state` as a query string parameter in your Cloud Function, as explained here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize-response

In the Cloud Function, you can get the value of `state` by doing `req.query.state`, see the Cloud Functions [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) on this point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you. By using this method you will be able to call the user's `uid` from anywhere

Install the provider package (https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-installing-tab-) by adding it to you pubspec.yaml dependencies.

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^3.1.0+1
```

Next, create a new dart file called auth.dart (you can name it anything you want..

Inside that file create a new class called Auth, like this:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Auth {

String userId;

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

String get userId {
    return _userId;
  }

void getUserID() async{
    FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    _userId = user.uid;
  }

}
```

Then in your `main.dart` file

import the Provider package by adding this import:

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
```

and also in the `main.dart` file, right before your MaterialApp is returned (`return MaterialApp...)`

Wrap it with a new widget like this:

```
Consumer<Auth>(
 builder: (ctx, auth, _) => MaterialApp(...),),
```

Now, inside any widget where you want to call the user's Id you can do this..

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final auth = Provider.of<Auth>(context);

return Container(
 child: Text(auth.uid);
 );
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes this is an app written in dart/flutter. what would it be your answer?

Comment: Hi @Cris thanks for your feedback. This is a good solution but only in the client. I was looking to get something like this but for a cloud function. I realised there is no way to get the userId other than passing this information to my https request